# WooCommerce Shipping Calculator (shipping-calculator.php) - PHP Override - Zip Code Only

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

In need of some suggestions here.

I'm attempting to edit my shipping calculator (not checkout calculator as based on https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

I'm going through the code and I'm unable to replicate what I'm trying to accomplish as seen here: [image: The Calculator]

I just want to hide the State & Country options and make it so you can only enter a zip code. I've tried the obvious like hiding it in the CSS style sheet/override just making the width/length "0".

```
#add_payment_method .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table select, .woocommerce-cart .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table select, .woocommerce-checkout .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table select {
width: 0 height: 0;}
```

But it's still requiring the country state in order to calculate correctly. I've even set up on the back end of woocommerce to just calculate "1 zip code (ex: 48081)" for example, and entering just that zip code even though it has a rate allocated to it, and unfortunately that didn't resolve it.

I am now in the SFTP of my server VIA FileZilla, backing up the shipping-calculator.php file and editing it accordingly and I was wondering if there was something specific in this code that would help me accomplish that:

```
<?php
/**
 * Shipping Calculator
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/shipping-calculator.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.8
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_shipping_calc' ) || ! WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ) {
    return;
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shipping_calculator' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-shipping-calculator" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">

    <p><a href="#" class="shipping-calculator-button"><?php _e( 'Calculate Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a></p>

    <section class="shipping-calculator-form" style="display:none;">

        <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_country_field">
            <select name="calc_shipping_country" id="calc_shipping_country" class="country_to_state" rel="calc_shipping_state">
                <option value=""><?php _e( 'Select a country&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
                <?php
                    foreach( WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries() as $key => $value )
                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '"' . selected( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), esc_attr( $key ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</option>';
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_state_field">
            <?php
                $current_cc = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
                $current_r  = WC()->customer->get_shipping_state();
                $states     = WC()->countries->get_states( $current_cc );

                // Hidden Input
                if ( is_array( $states ) && empty( $states ) ) {

                    ?><input type="hidden" name="calc_shipping_state" id="calc_shipping_state" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'State / county', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /><?php

                // Dropdown Input
                } elseif ( is_array( $states ) ) {

                    ?><span>
                        <select name="calc_shipping_state" id="calc_shipping_state" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'State / county', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <option value=""><?php _e( 'Select a state&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
                            <?php
                                foreach ( $states as $ckey => $cvalue )
                                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $ckey ) . '" ' . selected( $current_r, $ckey, false ) . '>' . __( esc_html( $cvalue ), 'woocommerce' ) .'</option>';
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </span><?php

                // Standard Input
                } else {

                    ?><input type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_r ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'State / county', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" name="calc_shipping_state" id="calc_shipping_state" /><?php

                }
            ?>
        </p>

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_city', false ) ) : ?>

            <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_city_field">
                <input type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->customer->get_shipping_city() ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'City', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" name="calc_shipping_city" id="calc_shipping_city" />
            </p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_postcode', true ) ) : ?>

            <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_postcode_field">
                <input type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode() ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Postcode / ZIP', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" name="calc_shipping_postcode" id="calc_shipping_postcode" />
            </p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <p><button type="submit" name="calc_shipping" value="1" class="button"><?php _e( 'Update Totals', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button></p>

        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>
    </section>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_calculator' ); ?>
```

EDIT: (4 hours after original post)

Changes I've made so far:

```
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_country_field">
        <select name="calc_shipping_country" id="calc_shipping_country" class="country_to_state" rel="calc_shipping_state">
            <option value="US" selected="selected">United States (US)</option>
            <?php
                foreach( WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries() as $key => $value )
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '"' . selected( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), esc_attr( $key ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</option>';
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>
```

^ I've updated the country field with that code, forcing customers to the US upon calculating shipping & am able to hide that direct input VIA overriding the CSS structure of the page. I know this may be a long way around the initial answer I need but am currently working on this intently. All I need now is the Zip Code to correspond with the state correctly. Unless again, someone suggests something entirely different.

Comment: I updated my post literally about 3 minutes ago before you posted, the last code text box there is the force change I implemented on the <option value=""?></option> Instead of allowing the drop down.

Comment: Slowly but surely making progress on this lol

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by updating the initial countries choice selection to ONLY the united states, so mind you, this will only work in a single country for people who may stumble upon this by editing the PHP code from:

```
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_country_field">
        <select name="calc_shipping_country" id="calc_shipping_country" class="country_to_state" rel="calc_shipping_state">
            <option value=""><?php _e( 'Select a country&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
            <?php
                foreach( WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries() as $key => $value )
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '"' . selected( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), esc_attr( $key ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</option>';
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>
```

to

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_country_field">
    <select name="calc_shipping_country" id="calc_shipping_country" class="country_to_state" rel="calc_shipping_state">
        <option value="US" selected="selected">United States (US)</option>
        <?php
            foreach( WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries() as $key => $value )
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '"' . selected( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), esc_attr( $key ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</option>';
        ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Then making a custom page for the cart and overriding the CSS stylesheet with:

```
#add_payment_method .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table select, .woocommerce-cart .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table select, .woocommerce-checkout .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table select {
width: 0 height: 0;}
```

Once you've done all this you need to go into the back end and adjust your Shipping Zone settings to reflect each states Zip Code range like so: (Remove the states after, those were just there for reference.)

[Shipping Zones - WooCommerce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr7eJ.png)

Another big thank you to @LoicTheAztec though for helping me, his way was initially the answer I was looking for doing it all just through PHP but I got lazy and adjusted the CSS stylesheet lol.

Comment: As your answer is the good to your question, you should accept it (little greyed checkmark beside your answer) … I have up voted your answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code Updated

If you are selling only in the states as your question update is confirming:

> You could try to replace line 54 on shipping calculator template: 
>   **`if ( is_array( $states ) && empty( $states ) ) {`** 
>   by 
>    **`if ( empty($current_r) ) {`**
>
> And line 59 replace: 
>  
>   **`} elseif ( is_array( $states ) ) {`** 
>   by 
>   **`} elseif ( false ) {`**
>
> This way: 
>   1) if customer is logged in and shipping state is defined, you get the pre-filled **standard imput**
>   2) if customer isn't logged in, you get the Hidden imput field (empty).

Try it, as I can't test it really, because it depends a lot on woocommerce settings too.